# Why is nobody voting on this question, but so many people are voting on the comments?

Tags: discussion, voting, specific-question

I'm curious why at least 4 people have voted on the comments without voting on the question, here:

[image]

Voting wasn't this way from 2020-2021 and much of 2022. Similar questions in the past have had over 10 upvotes! What is so good about the comments compared to the question itself? The quote in this question: [We hit rock bottom last week, in voting. What can we do now to encourage people to vote more?](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/288/5) advocates not to consider voting to be a "reward" for "exceptional" posts. How would you feel if your publications didn't get cited or it seemed like they were being "viewed 41 times" but with no one caring positively about the paper? SE posts usually don't take as much time to write as papers, but a lot of people do put a lot of effort into SE posts.

Was it the comment that's implying/suggesting/insinuating that the question is off-topic here, that made people hesitate to vote on the question? If you saw the question and didn't vote, please let us know your reasons so that we can continue trying to grow this site positively and learn what works and what doesn't!

I asked a similar question about a year ago here: [Why did this question not get any votes in the last 5.5 months despite getting 61 views and comments from at least 3 different people?](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/366/5)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because I am getting downvoted, maybe by people who are offended by me saying "applications require less skills".